# Find an update object from an array in react using useContext

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, use-context

This is a tricky question and I have been having a hard time figuring out this. First of all I'm using useContext to make a global state. The global state will hold and serve an array with objects. I have a form rendered together with every object. The form will have an input with an value.
My goal is to be able to find the object and update the value. For example the input in Item1 will update "20" to whatever new number that are being inputted, same with Item2
What is happened now I that every time I submit an input, a whole new array are being created instead on updated. I know its a whole easier way to achieve this, but I need this array to be in a global state.

here's link to my sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-wildflower-h5hhw?file=/src/App.js

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is confusing, and please provide code, not a link to some sandbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify which `Array Item` you want to update. First of all you need to specify which item you need to update. For this i've passed the `value id` through the `card props`

```
<Card
  name={value.name}
  value={value.Itemvalue}
  key={value.id}
  id={value.id}
/>
```

And i've used `map` to update the specific `object`

```
const updatedData = value.map((obj) => {
    if (obj.id === id) {
        return { ...obj, Itemvalue: itemValue };
    } else return obj;
});
updateValue(updatedData);
```

And here is the working [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/young-violet-s00lz?file=/src/UpdateForm.js)

Comment: Thank you sir. Wasted a whole night just to figure out this, and you made it look so simple.

Comment: @jan glad to know, it helped. Please mark this answer as accepted answer. That will help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're adding a new element everything the form is updated. Which is different from what you need. Pass `id` to the update function, so that you can update that particular item.

#### Your code

```js
  const addValue = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // You're not updating existing element, instead adding a new value.
    updateValue((prevItems) => [...prevItems, { Itemvalue: itemValue }]);
  };

// ...

    <form onSubmit={addValue}>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="price"
        Value={itemValue} // --> Typo here
        onChange={updateItemValue}
      />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
```

You should pass the `id` as props instead of getting it from context. So `<Add />` knows exactly where to update the value.

#### Corrected code

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { ValueContext } from "./ValueContext";

const Add = ({ id }) => { // --> Passing id from <Card /> 
  const [itemValue, setItemValue] = useState("");
  const [value, updateValue] = useContext(ValueContext);

  const updateItemValue = (event) => {
    setItemValue(event.target.value);
  };

  const addValue = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    updateValue((prevItems) => {
      const index = prevItems.findIndex(x => x.id === id);
      const updatedItem = {
        ...prevItems[index],
        Itemvalue: itemValue
      }

      return [
        ...prevItems.slice(0, index),
        updatedItem, // --> Updating the item, instead of creating new one
        ...prevItems.slice(index + 1)
      ]
    });
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={addValue}>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="price"
        Value={itemValue}
        onChange={updateItemValue}
      />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Add;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code worked as well!